# Staging roles in Kentico 9 is only syncing Module permissions, not Page Type or Custom Table ones

Tags: asp.net, kentico

**Important note**

Read Update 3 below first. This has been confirmed as a bug in Kentico.

**Original post:**

I hope someone can help me with a really frustrating issue. I have a local single-server multi-site (2 sites) Kentico 9 instance. I also have a another environment set up as a web farm with 2 servers. The former is configured to synchronize with the latter via the Staging module.

Everything works fine except for Roles. I'm finding that when a role is changed and synchronized, it's copying any permissions set against modules, but any changes made to permissions for page types or custom tables are not synced. In fact, if I add these permissions on the target then re-sync I see this permissions are actually wiped out. So the sync task is behaving as though I've removed all these permissions at source.

I'm sure I've set staging up correct. As I say, it's working for all other objects. My source has 2 staging servers configured, once for each site, and I've added the following web.config keys to ensure global objects are staged correctly:

```
<add key="CMSStagingTreatServerNamesAsInstances" value="true" />
<add key="CMSStagingLogGlobalObjectsOnlyForAssignedSites" value="true" />
```

Originally I had a series of objects excluded from staging in a `CMSModuleLoader` `Init` method, but I've completely removed all these and still observing the same behaviour. I've also tried with the above web.config keys removed. So as far as I'm concerned this has been tested in a vanilla staging setup.

Any advice you have would be appreciated.

**Update**

I've discovered that the same thing happens when I export roles to the target using the import/export feature. So right now I have no means of deploying roles. I should also point out that there are no errors or warnings in the event log. Also, it might be worth mentioning that I have staging configured for all changes except for content.

**Update 2**

(Please ignore this update - I had configured staging servers incorrectly. See comments)

Having investigated further, I'm now seeing that the same role is being created on both sites by the staging task, so I'm ending up with 2 roles on the target both with the same code name. I'm guessing this might be the cause of the problem. Is this a Kentico bug? The role in question is a site-level role, not a global role. When synchronizing I'm choosing 'all' servers but my understanding from [this post](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/global-objects-staging-in-multisite-setup) was that global objects would only be synced once in this case. Although I'm not sure if site-level roles are even technically global objects. In any case there should not be the possibility of syncing a site's role to a different target site.

**Update 3**

Kentico have now acknowledged that this is a bug and have committed to fixing within their standard 7-day. They will be releasing their fix as a hotfix. I'll update here when this happens.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - how many target servers have you defined? Even if your environment has 2 or more servers in web farm you should always define only 1 target server. The reason is that those instances in WF are actually using same db so that might explain why you end up with 2 same roles.

Comment: I've defined 2 target servers. But that's because both environments have 2 sites. Is that not correct?

Comment: To clarify, I had made the mistake of creating two staging servers on each site so that would explain the behaviour in Update 2 above. However, I've now corrected this so each site has one staging server, and I'm still observing the same problem.